# How to integrate $\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{dx}{(2+\cos(x))(3+\cos(x))}$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, substitution

The integral is

$$\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{dx}{(2+\cos(x))(3+\cos(x))}$$

I did try Tangent half-angle substitution but only got:

$$2\int^{2\pi}_0 \frac{dt}{9t^2-t^4-12}$$

which does not seem to be easier... am I wrong on the way? Or is there easier way?

Comment: You are well on the way. You can now factor the denominator and do a partial fraction decomposition.

Comment: Check the limits of integration. Looks like you didn't take the substitution into account there. To that end it may be better to think of the original limits as being from $-\pi$ to $\pi$. Makes no difference to the integral due to periodicity.

Comment: set $$t^2=a$$ and go on

Comment: This can be done nicely as a contour integral in the complex plane

Comment: Another way would be to work in the Fourier domain transforming multiplication to convolution and division to deconvolution. Would probably give the same result as to split to two terms and expand geometric series.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint...You could split it first by writing $$\frac{1}{(2+c)(3+c)}=\frac{1}{2+c}-\frac{1}{3+c}$$ then use the $t=\tan\frac x2$ substitution

Note that you can use symmetry to change the integral from $\int_0^{2\pi}$ to $2\times \int_0^{\pi}$

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how you arrived at:

> I did try Tangent half-angle substitution but only got:
>
> $$2\int^{2\pi}_0 \frac{dt}{9t^2-t^4-12}$$

With $t = \tan\left( \tfrac{x}{2} \right)$, you have $\cos x = \tfrac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}$ and $\tfrac{dx}{dt} = \tfrac{2}{1+t^2}$; so:
$$\int \frac{\mbox{d}x}{(2+ \cos x)(3+ \cos x)} \to \int \frac{1}{\left(2+ \tfrac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}\right)\left(3+ \tfrac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}\right)}\frac{2 \, }{1+t^2}\mbox{d}t$$
Now simplifying and splitting (partial fractions):
$$\int \frac{1+t^2}{\left(2+ t^2\right)\left(3+ t^2\right)}\,\mbox{d}t
 = \int \frac{2}{3+ t^2}\,\mbox{d}t-\int \frac{1}{2+ t^2}\,\mbox{d}t$$

Answer (score 1):

You can see that $\cos (2\pi - x) = \cos x$ and hence the integral from $0$ to $2\pi$ is twice the integral from $0$ to $\pi$. Thus we have
\begin{align}
I &= 2\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{dx}{(2 + \cos x)(3 + \cos x)}\notag\\
&= 2\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{dx}{2 + \cos x} - 2\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{dx}{3 + \cos x}\notag\\
&= 2\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{4 - 1}} - 2\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{9 - 1}}\notag\\
&= 2\pi\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} - \frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}\right)\notag
\end{align}
The integral $$\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{dx}{a + b\cos x}$$ for $a > |b|$ is calculated using the substitution $$(a + b\cos x)(a - b\cos y) = a^{2} - b^{2}$$ and it easily evaluates to $\pi/\sqrt{a^{2} - b^{2}}$.

Comment: I don't understand how you arrived at a^2-b^2 from (a+bcsosx)(a-bcosy)

Comment: @Mockingbird: it is a substitution from variable $x$ to $y$ and we need to calculate $dx/dy$ so that the $dx$ part in the integral can be replaced with $dy$. Note that the substitution maps $[0,\pi]$ to itself.

Answer (score 1):

I will propose an approach that uses complex analysis. The idea is to write $\cos x= (e^{ix} + e^{-ix})/2$ and then to rewrite the integral in such a way that a parametrised contour integral appears. Then a routine application of the Residue Theorem will yield the desired result.

As stated, write:

$$I=\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{dx}{(2+\mathrm{cos}(x))(3+\mathrm{cos}(x))}=\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{dx}{\left(2 + \frac{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}}{2}\right)\left(3 + \frac{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}}{2}\right)}\\ =4\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{dx}{(4 + e^{ix} + e^{-ix})(6 + e^{ix} + e^{-ix})}\\ =4\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{(e^{ix})^2}{\left(1 + 4e^{ix} + (e^{ix})^2\right)\left(1+ 6e^{ix} +(e^{ix})^2\right)}\ dx$$

Now, through the parametrisation $z=e^{ix}$ notice that this last expression equals $-i$ times the contour integral

$$J=\oint_{|z|=1}\frac{z}{(1+ 4z + z^2)(1 + 6z + z^2)}\ dz$$

where the integral is taken counter-clockwise about the unit circle. To evaluate $J$ we need the residues in the two poles of the integrand that are contained inside the unit circle $|z|=1$, namely the poles $z_1=-2 + \sqrt{3}$ and $z_2=-3 + 2\sqrt{2}$. After a tedious calculation we obtain

$$\mathrm{Res}_{z=z_1}\ f(z)=\frac{1}{4\sqrt{3}}\\ \mathrm{Res}_{z=z_2}\ f(z)=-\frac{1}{8\sqrt{2}}$$ where $f(z)$ is the integrand of $J$.

Hence by the Residue Theorem: $$J=2 \pi i \left(\frac{1}{4\sqrt{3}} -\frac{1}{8\sqrt{2}}\right)$$ which yields the desired result: $$I=-4iJ=\pi \left(\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}} -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right).$$

Comment: Interesting enough your answer and StackTD answer is different. Although I think his method is legit.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[8px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\int_{0}^{2\pi}{\dd x \over \bracks{2 + \cos\pars{x}}\bracks{3 +\cos\pars{x}}} =
\left.-\int_{0}^{2\pi}{\dd x \over \mu + \cos\pars{x}}
\,\right\vert_{\ \mu\ =\ 2}^{\ \mu\ =\ 3}
\\[5mm] = &\
\left.-\int_{0}^{2\pi}{\dd x \over \mu + 1 - 2\sin^{2}\pars{x/2}}
\,\right\vert_{\ \mu\ =\ 2}^{\ \mu\ =\ 3} =
\left.-2\int_{0}^{\pi}{\dd x \over \mu + 1 - 2\sin^{2}\pars{x}}
\,\right\vert_{\ \mu\ =\ 2}^{\ \mu\ =\ 3}
\\[5mm] = &\
\left.-2\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}{\dd x \over \mu + 1 - 2\cos^{2}\pars{x}}
\,\right\vert_{\ \mu\ =\ 2}^{\ \mu\ =\ 3} =
\left.-4\int_{0}^{\pi/2}{\sec^{2}\pars{x} \over
\pars{\mu + 1}\sec^{2}\pars{x} - 2}\,\dd x
\,\right\vert_{\ \mu\ =\ 2}^{\ \mu\ =\ 3}
\\[5mm] = &\
\left.-4\int_{0}^{\pi/2}{\sec^{2}\pars{x} \over
\pars{\mu + 1}\tan^{2}\pars{x} + \mu - 1}\,\dd x
\,\right\vert_{\ \mu\ =\ 2}^{\ \mu\ =\ 3}
\\[5mm] = &\
\left.-4\,{1 \over \mu - 1}\,\root{\mu - 1 \over \mu + 1}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}
{\root{\pars{\mu + 1}/\pars{\mu - 1}}\sec^{2}\pars{x} \over
\bracks{\root{\pars{\mu + 1}/\pars{\mu - 1}}\tan\pars{x}}^{2} + 1}\,\dd x
\,\right\vert_{\ \mu\ =\ 2}^{\ \mu\ =\ 3}
\\[5mm] = &\
\left.-\,{4 \over \root{\mu^{2} - 1}}\int_{0}^{\infty}
{\dd x \over x^{2} + 1}\,\dd x\,\right\vert_{\ \mu\ =\ 2}^{\ \mu\ =\ 3} =
\left.-\,{2\pi \over \root{\mu^{2} - 1}}
\,\right\vert_{\ \mu\ =\ 2}^{\ \mu\ =\ 3} =
-\,{2\pi \over \root{3^{2} - 1}} + {2\pi \over \root{2^{2} - 1}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\bbx{\ds{\pars{{2\root{3} \over 3} - {\root{2} \over 2}}\pi}} \approx 1.4062
\end{align}